# Existe algum mecanismo de supressão de erro em C# parecido com o do arroba PHP?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, diretivas-de-compilação

Estou estudando C#, porém estou acostumado a programar em PHP.

Eu sei que em PHP é possível suprimir algumas mensagens de erro colocando o `@` (arroba) no início da expressão.

Por exemplo, se eu quisesse que a variável `$a` não emitisse o `Erro Notice`, por ela não existir, eu simplesmente poderia usar um `@`.

```
echo $a; // Notice: undefined variable 'a'
echo @$a;// Sem erros
```

É claro que não é uma das melhores práticas, mas na verdade não estou aqui para saber o que é boa prática ou não, e sim quero aprendendo o C# e quero aprender tudo!

Existe um mecanismo de supressão de mensagens de erros em C# da mesma forma que o PHP?

Comment: Embora seja uma má pratica utilizar @ para suprimir erros, em C#, também é possível fazer algo do tipo:  `On Error Resume Next "ignored error" System("pause")`.

Comment: @IvanFerrer isso é VB.NET. Não se aplica no C#.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Existe sim, é o [`#pragma warning`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma-warning?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Algumas considerações devem ser feitas.

Isto existe só em tempo de compilação já que esta é um diretiva de compilação. Nada mudará na execução do código.

C# tem a filosofia de relativamente poucos *warnings* (agora aumentou um pouco), prefere-se o erro ou funcionar sem restrições. A linguagem foi pensada para isto.

O seu uso deve ser extremamente raro. A maioria dos códigos nunca terão isto.

Ele é útil quando se faz alguma coisa normalmente estranha que realmente pode dar um problema e não tem outra forma de resolver via código. Ou seja, você sabe **realmente** que não tem problema algum naquela situação e precisa informar isso ao compilador. Um *warning* não é um erro, o compilador sabe que o programador pode estar certo em raras circunstâncias.

Ninguém coloca isso do nada, em geral se percebe que ele é necessário depois de ver o código compilando e mostrando um *warning* específico. Depois de muito pensar e ter certeza que não tem outro jeito, aí pode-se desabilitar **especificamente** esse *warning* através do seu código. Assim se um dia aparecer outro *warning* em uma manutenção, ele será apresentado. Nunca desabilite todos *warnings* (não especificando o(s) número(s) do(s) *warning(s)*).

Seu efeito vale por um bloco de código até ser desligado:

```
#pragma warning disable 168 //desabilitei aqui por causa de....
    ... código ...
#pragma warning restore
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/PragmaWarning.cs).

Há a recomendação de sempre comentar porque está usado isto. Se não conseguir dar um bom motivo, tem algo errado aí. Não vale culpar o compilador :)

Existem outros [`#pragma`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para dar outros tipos de instruções ao compilador. Um deles é o [`#pragma checksum`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma-checksum?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Também existe o [`#warning`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-warning?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é usado para o seu código gerar um *warning* para o compilador. Isto provavelmente deve ser usado condicionalmente. Ou em algo que não deveria mais ser usado (ainda que exista outra solução para isto). Raro uso, como toda diretiva de compilação deve ser.

[Tem várias diretivas de compilação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que afetam o funcionamento da compilação e tem efeito secundário sobre o código.

Comment: É sempre bom lembrar que suprimir Warnings é diferente de suprimir gambiarras